# If $u$ is uniform on the ball and $A$ is a matrix, what is $E[\|Au\|^2]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, linear-transformations

For $u$ uniform on $\mathbb{C}^n$'s unit ball and $A$ linear from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^m$, what is the expectation of $\|Au\|^2$?

---

If $A$ is square, diagonalizable to $a_1,\dots,a_n,$  the answer is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \|a_i\|^2:$ $u$ has $n$ orthonormal components $v_i$ each with coefficient $\alpha_i$ and associated diagonal $a_i$. Then $\|Au\|^2=\sum_i |\alpha_i|^2\|a_i\|^2.$ Then take the expectation. What about in general?

Comment: I think it's still $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \|a_i\|^2$ for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in general is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \|a_i\|^2$ where the $a_i$ are the singular values of $A$:

Very similar to the proof in the OP, take a singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^\ast$. Let $\alpha_i$ be the coordinates in the column space of $V$, of vector $u$ uniform on the ball. Thus, $u=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i$, each $v_i$ a column of $V$. Then, $\|Au\|=\|\Sigma V^\ast u\|$ since unitary transformations preserve norm. Thus, $\|Au\|^2 = \|\Sigma V^\ast u\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i^2 a_i^2$, where $r \le \min(n,m)$ is the rank of $A$ (i.e number of nonzero singular values). Now, take the expectation of both sides and use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 = 1$, so that by symmetry, $\mathbb E \alpha_i^2 = 1/n$ for all $i = 1,\ldots,n$. You get $E\|Au\|^2 = (1/n)\sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2 = (1/n)\text{Trace}(A^TA)$ as claimed.

Comment: Very nice argument.